# System.DllNotFoundException in console application C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, development-environment

I have just drag and drop a project from a computer to an other, in order to work on mine. But I have an exception that I'm not able to fix when I run the project

Here it's my sample code where the exception is:

`CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));`

My Storage connection string is in my app.config file.

The .dll missing is fusion.dll according to the error, but it's not either in the original folder so I don't understand.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Does the machine it doesn't work on have the appropriate .Net framework(s) installed?

Comment: Fusion.dll is a framework runtime DLL, you cannot run code without it.  You'll have to fix that machine, reinstall the .NET framework to get somewhere.  Also significant odds that you simply mis-interpreted the error message and you actually just forgot to copy an assembly.  We can't see it from here.

Comment: @phuzi: thanks for your answer. It's strange because when I start a new project it works well... I would like to work on the new visual studio for Mac OS, maybe it's not totally performing

Comment: @Jeremy You shouldn't have the same problem if you're using .Net Core.